# I want to convert speech to text in WPF . How can I do this ??

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to convert speech to text in WPF . How can I do this ?

Answer (score 7):

Start by taking a look at the [Microsoft Speech API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.aspx) (SAPI)

Comment: Yeah, this comes built in with Windows (XP and above I think), and will do speech to text.  It has a managed code API so you can use it with C# in your WPF app.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.aspx

Answer (score 5):

WPF is used to build user interfaces, not algorithms. This is a C#,or even a .NET related question. Try to start with an Hello World program instead of such a big task. You'll progress step by step.

Comment: Ok thanx Ribon ..please Give me guideline ..tht how can i create that project in c# ??

Comment: What type of question is that? "How can I build a bridge plz gief me tutorialz thanks u". Sit down and do some research.

Answer (score 4):

WPF is a presentation framework.  It doesn't do text-to-speech or speech-to-text.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, this is not a simple solution for it. You must use voice recognition algorithm.

You can start a project in **Visual Studio 2010** by the clicking *File -> New -> Project ...* and choicing *Visual C# -> WPF Application*

Learning guide you can find at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/cc136611.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Not an easy task - very specialist in fact - but as a start you might look at using soundex to match words in a dictionary (db or flat file).

This will not give you grammatical checking, and probably won't be that accurate, but will give you a working framework that you can build on.

Of course, before you do any of that, you need to manage the sound file to pick out the sounds, spaces, rhythm etc. and convert them into a value that you can manipulate within your code.

You're looking at a LOT of man hours. Some people devote their careers to this.

Answer (score 1):

It's an open research problem. But you can buy commercial packages for it I think.

See for example: http://www.nuance.co.uk/naturallyspeaking/products/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

Please try google, you can find a lot of samples like this -

WPF Text To Speech UI -

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc998523.aspx

Converting Text to Speech in a C# WPF Application-

> http://www.redmondpie.com/converting-text-to-speech-in-a-c-wpf-application/

Comment: That's the opposite (easier) problem.